# generated file related to entity mapping - what is it, and is it reliably re-auto-generated?

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, auto-generate

I had a file auto-generated, called Core.Views.cs, inside a folder where we have a Core.edmx file.  This looks like something related to the entity framework, although I've not come across this specific type of auto-generated file before.  The file starts like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.296
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewGenerationAttribute(typeof(Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews.ViewsForBaseEntitySetsA6A322F63F6E541F50AC0C3927F34D34A0332BA66EF2300CE900CF04516540EA))]

namespace Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews
{
```

- If I check it into source control, it breaks our TFS build as the build process seems to be trying to re-generate the file so it creates a conflict
- What does this file do, and is it always reliably regenerated from source code?

Comment: So, don't check it in. Delete it, open the .edmx file, then check to see if it is re-generated. If _you_ didn't generate it, then someone else did.

Comment: So generation of this file would definitely have been triggered by opening the Core.edmx?  I was presuming the two files are linked...